# Is ‘for’ a complementizer or a preposition in ‘prefer for John to stay’

Tags: syntax, grammar, parts-of-speech, clauses, grammatical-category

As the title says, in ‘prefer for John to stay’, is ‘for’ a complementizer and the following is a CP, or a preposition?

Comment: I'd say it is a subordinator, a special marker for _to_-infinitivals that contain a subject, cf. "For John to stay would be a disaster".

Comment: I agree with BillJ, there's only one case where 'for' is realised as a head of C in *to*-infinitivals, e.g., "[IP [CP C For [IP him to [VP defeat the boxer]]] would be surprising]".

Comment: It's traditionally parsed as part of the _for...to_ infinitive complementizer. _For_ marks the subject, _to_ marks the verb of the infinitive clause. When the subject is missing, as it often is, the _for_ goes with it, except in some lects that retain _for to_. As @Tutsu points out, the only place where _for_ is required is when it opens the sentence, because its a push marker for the parser to start on a subordinate clause instead of the main. But it's often optionally retained. If you want to give it a special epicyclic distinction, it still works the same way.

Answer (score 3):

there is some confusion in the other answers to this question. let me be clear: on any understanding of the term "complementizer," the word *for* is indeed a complementizer in the context you give. *for* heads a non-finite CP. allow me to give a sense of the sheer enormity of evidence pointing in this direction.

the main thrust of the evidence is in establishing a clear parallelism between *for*-clauses and other sorts of clauses headed by complementizers, especially *that*-clauses. the parallelism serves to show that *for*-clauses can be described as standard CPs, as shown below. note that infinitival *to* is a non-finite auxiliary verb, another fact for which there is a preponderance of evidence (see Bob Levine’s paper “auxiliaries – to’s company”).

[image]

as mentioned, the CP headed by *that* is finite (tensed) while the CP headed by *for* is non-finite (not tensed). we can take this to be a selectional difference between the two Cs; *that* selects for a finite TP complement, while *for* selects for a non-finite TP complement. see the appendix at the end of this answer for more details on *selection*.

now, on to the evidence for the parallelism. i’ll mainly cite arguments from **bresnan 1972** and **huddleston & pullum 2002**, with points 1-5 coming from bresnan and points 6-8 coming from huddleston & pullum (with some overlap). point 9 is surely not original to me, but i don’t know of a source for it off the top of my head.

#### 1. *for* fails to co-occur with other complementizers like *that* and *whether*.

bresnan notes that two members of the set of complementizers cannot appear in the same clause together. this suggests they serve the same role in the clause (i.e. they are all complementizers). the example below illustrates with *that* and *for*.

(1) 
a. *Marie asked that for us to leave her alone. 
b. *For that he refuses would not be surprising.
(bresnan p30)

#### 2. *for* occupies the same position in the clause as other complementizers (i.e. complementizers are clause-initial).

this is noted by bresnan 1972 p32-33, as well as huddleston & pullum 2002 p1183

(2) 
a. it is important [<sub>CLAUSE</sub> that detailed records be kept].
b. it is important [<sub>CLAUSE</sub> for detailed records to be kept]
(huddleston & pullum p1183)

#### 3. *for* occurs in the same paradigms as *that*, just with non-finite clauses instead of finite clauses.

The following examples are from Bresnan p37, where she notes that *for*-clauses can have the same sorts of syntactic roles that *that*-clauses can. similar observations can be found in huddleston & pullum 2002 p1182.

(3) Object Complementation
a. I know [<sub>OBJECT</sub> that he is wise].
b. I prefer [<sub>OBJECT</sub> for you to speak English].

(4) Subject Complementation
a. [<sub>SUBJECT</sub>That he was alone was obvious from the report.
b. [<sub>SUBJECT</sub> For you to leave right now] would be inconvenient.

(5) Nominal Complementation
a. The idea [<sub>COMP-N</sub> that nobody will survive] is apalling.
b. The command [<sub>COMP-N</sub> for all troops to move out] was given Friday.

(6) Copular Complementation
a. The problem is [<sub>COMP-COPULA</sub> that you are arrogant].
b. The command is [<sub>COMP-COPULA</sub> for all troops to move out].

#### 4. Non-finite clauses headed by *for* can be extraposed in just the same was as finite clauses headed by *that*.

bresnan observes that, just like finite *that*-clauses, *for*-clauses can be extraposed to sentence-final position. when this happens, an expletive **it** occupies the clauses' original position in the main sentence. the example below is bresnan's, with extraposition taking place from subject position. thus, expletive **it** occupies subject position in the main sentence.

(7) 
a. **It** should not be as important as you make it sound [that they agree with us].
b. **It** should not be as important as you make it sound [for them to agree with us].
(Bresnan p38-39)

#### 5. *for*, just like *that*, is sometimes optional when it heads a complement clause, but is always obligatory when it heads a subject clause.

(8) 
a. I don’t think [ (that) you should have said it]. 
b. I want [ (for) you to help me].
(bresnan p.39)

(9) 
a. [ *(That) he was alone] was obvious from the report.
b. [ *(For) you to leave right now] would be inconvenient.
(bresnan p.40. note the notation is intended to show that *that* and *for* are obligatory here)

#### 6. *for*-clauses can have expletive subjects

huddleston & pullum’s basic argument is that the *for*-phrase is a clause, just like any other, save that it is non-finite. they emphasize that the subject of the *for*-clause acts just as we would expect the subject of any clause to. the subject can be an expletive *there*, for instance, something that is typically reserved for subject position.

(10)
a. It is essential for there to be no misunderstanding on this point.
b. It is essential that there should be no misunderstanding on this point
(the a example is from huddleston & pullum p1183. i added the b example for comparison)

now it might be worth noting that expletive *there* can raise to object, even being able to raise to object of preposition, for instance in the following examples.

(11)
a. You can always count on there to be rain.
b. I can almost always rely on there to be a group of students playing Ultimate Frisbee every day at 3:30 in the afternoon
(b example from culicover & jackendoff 2005 p210)

however, there is a huge range of properties with respect to which *for*-phrases diverge from the *on* cases in (11), such that a similar raising analysis of *there* is not possible with *for*. just to give one example, *on* plus the subject of the infinitival clause forms a constituent, which can be fronted. this is not possible with *for*:

(12)
a. [On whom]<sub>i</sub> can you always count __<sub>i</sub> to do a good job?
b. *[For whom]<sub>i</sub> do you want __<sub>i</sub> to win?

this points towards an analysis of the *on* cases as involving a true PP, such that the preposition plus infinitival subject form a constituent. this is not a possible analysis with *for* clauses.

#### 7. *for*-clauses can have idiom subjects

huddleston & pullum (p1183) further point out that the subject of a *for*-clause can be part of an idiom, something that’s also true of the subject of a *that*-clause.

(13)
a. he called for close tabs to be kept on the new recruits
b. he hoped that close tabs would be kept on the new recruits
(a example from huddleston & pullum p1183. i added the b example for comparison)

#### 8. placement of adverbial particles

huddleston & pullum (p1183) also note that the placement of adverbial particles like *both* in *for*-clauses mirrors the placement of such particles in *that*-clauses. this suggests that the subject of a *for*-clause occupies the same syntactic position as the subject of a *that*-clause.

(14)
a. it’s necessary for **both** your parents to sign the form.
b. it’s necessary for the form to be signed by **both** your parents.
c. It’s necessary for your parents **both** to sign the form.
(huddleston & pullum 1183)

compare with the placement of *both* in a *that*-clause:

(15)
a. it’s likely that **both** your parents will sign the form.
b. it’s likely that the form will be signed by **both** your parents.
c. It’s likely that your parents **both** will sign the form.

#### 9. extraction of the subject of a *for*-clause yields a complementizer-trace effect, just as extraction of the subject of a finite clause would

because many people are not familiar with the complementizer-trace phenomenon, i will explain a bit more here. one of the most-discussed phenomena in syntactic theory is the “comp-trace” effect, wherein the subject of an embedded clause cannot be extracted when that clause is headed by an overt complementizer. so for instance the canonical illustration would be:

(16)
a. Who<sub>i</sub> did you say __<sub>i</sub> won?
b. *Who<sub>i</sub> did you say that __<sub>i</sub> won?

notice that the complementizer can be overt with object extraction, just not with subject extraction.

(17)
Who<sub>i</sub> did you say (that) you like __<sub>i</sub>?

this is sometimes called the “that-trace” effect, but “comp-trace” is more accurate, as it applies with all complementizers, for example with *if* and *whether*, as well. since *if* and *whether* aren’t in free variation with null realizations, extraction of the subject of an *if* or *whether* clause is blocked.

(18)
a. *Who<sub>i</sub> did you ask if __<sub>i</sub> won?
a. ?Who<sub>i</sub> did you ask if I like __<sub>i</sub>?

(19)
a. *Who<sub>i</sub> do you wonder whether __<sub>i</sub> won?
a. ?Who<sub>i</sub> do you wonder whether I like __<sub>i</sub>?

*For*-clauses participate exactly as we would expect if they were structurally parallel to other clauses headed by complementizers. When *for* is overt, extraction of the subject is blocked. When *for* is null, extraction is allowed.

(20)
a. Who<sub>i</sub> do you want __<sub>i</sub> to win?
b. *Who<sub>i</sub> do you want for __<sub>i</sub> to win?

*For* is optional when the object is extracted, just as with the other complementizers.

(21)
Who<sub>i</sub> do you want (for) John to like __<sub>i</sub>?

thus *for* acts just as a complementizer would be expected to with respect to the comp-trace effect.

#### on two differences between *for* clauses and other CPs

there are sure to be more reasons than the ones cited above. these are just the ones that came to my mind without too much digging.

now, it might be worth noting two ways in which *for*-clauses differ from other sorts of CPs in english. first, *for*-clauses are non-finite. this is no reason to think that *for* is not a complementizer. there is no reason to stipulate that complementizers head finite clauses only, especially given that non-finite complementizers are by no means exclusive to english; they appear in a variety of languages, as a google scholar search for “non-finite complementizer” easily reveals.
second, the subject of a *for*-clause is marked with accusative case rather than nominative case (as would normally be the case in english). historically, the reason is that *for*-clauses are derived from prepositional phrases, which in english assign accusative case (or “objective” case of “oblique” case or whatever term one prefers). syntactically, the lack of nominative case has been related to non-finiteness. it is widely believed that nominative case is associated with tense. since *for*-clauses are non-finite, lacking tense, they can’t assign nominative case.

as with any phenomenon in syntax, really careful investigation reveals many interesting puzzles. if we look really closely, and examine a wide range of complex syntactic properties, we'll certainly find some further ways in which *for*-clauses differ from *that*-clauses. but our first response should not be to say that *for* is not a complementizer, or that it is some sort of exceptional construction. we should construct theories that capture whatever differences we find, while also capturing the deep parallelisms that exist between *for*-clauses and other clause types.

### references

Bresnan, J. W. (1972). Theory of complementation in English syntax. MIT.
Culicover, P. W., Culicover, P. W., Jackendoff, R. S., & Jackendoff, R. (2005). Simpler syntax. Oxford University Press.
Huddleston, R. D. & Pullum, G. P. (2002). The Cambridge grammar of the English language. Cambridge University Press.
Levine, R. D. (2012). Auxiliaries: To's company. Journal of Linguistics, 48(1), 187-203.

#### appendix: some basic background on selection

a commenter insists that the fact that *for*-clauses are non-finite disqualifies them from being CPs. however, as i pointed out, non-finite CPs are well-attested crosslinguistically, so there is no comparative reason for skepticism towards the analysis of *for*-phrases as non-finite CPs. in addition, as shown in great detail above, all evidence points towards *for*-phrases being structurally parallel to other English CPs, including *that*-phrases. there's no reason to think that CPs must be finite. thus, the idea that *for*-phrases are non-finite CPs is perfectly plausible.

that being the case, it's not entirely clear what the commenter has in mind. however, i think some light can be shed on the objection with the following comment, posted on a different answer:
 "In the phrase structure tree, the template is predetermined. Words are inserted into positions in the template. In this case, inserting for into the C position incorrectly predicts that the finite complement should be possible, since it is possible for the other Cs"

here the assumption seems to be that phrase structure representations are templates into which words are freely inserted. the given trees then make the wrong prediction, because they predict C can be filled by any C, T can be filled with any T, etc. Under this assumption, there's an incorrect prediction, because in fact T can't be just *any* T: with *that* in C, T has to be filled by a finite T, and with *for* in C, T has to be filled by a non-finite T.

to clarify, i do not assume that phrase structure representations are templates into which words are freely inserted. instead, it is known that syntactic representations are constrained by *selection* relations. we will say that *for* *selects* (or "subcategorizes") a *non-finite* TP as its complement, while *that* *selects* (or "subcategorizes") a *finite* TP as its complement.

it might be helpful to compare this instance of selection to other instances. a straightforward case occurs with determiners. (i will assume for accessibility's sake that N is the head of nominal phrases, not D. the argument works the exact same if one assumes D is the head). notice that the two noun phrases below are considered to have the same structure.

(22)
a. that dog
b. those dogs

in one case, we get a singular determiner *that*, and in the other, a plural determiner *those*. further, we can't switch the determiners, getting "those dog" or "that dogs." this is straightforwardly described as an instance of selection. we will say that singular nouns *select* singular determiners, not plural determiners. we will say that plural nouns *select* plural determiners, not singular determiners. notice that we don't want to say that singular nouns and plural nouns are different categories (they are both nouns), nor do we want to say singular determiners are a different category from plural determiners (they are both determiners).

we will use the same apparatus to describe the fact that *for* must have a non-finite clause as its complement, and that *that* must have a finite clause as its complement.

Comment: The answer conveniently postpones the key issue to the end, where it  then plays down the importance of the fact that the complementizer _for_, unlike the other complementizers, does not allow a finite clause as its complement. That key fact is certainly part of he reason for the OP to have asked the question in the first place. I have voted it down.

Comment: In your dictionary, does a complementizer introduce only a complement clause? If so, Is _for_ a complementizer in this example? _He's the right person for me to work with._

Answer (score 1):

I personally would say that it is not a complementizer.

For instance, if we compare the sentences:

> (1) Mark prefers for John to stay
>
> (2) John prefers to stay

I personally want to think of (1) and (2) as having the complement clause to be about the same, because they are both "(for John) to stay" but (2) has the John implied because it is correferential with the subject of "prefer." Because the "for" part is not necessary to  make it a relative, and "to" is already a complementizer that gives the clause the complement status, you can safely say that "for" is not likely to be a complementizer.

Comment: infinitival _to_ is not a complementizer, it is an auxiliary. see Levine, R. D. (2012). Auxiliaries: To's company. Journal of Linguistics, 48(1), 187-203.

Comment: The complementizer is _for...to_. The _for_ is usually missing, the _to_ is usually present, by rule in both cases. It you want to call it something else, feel free. It's your metalanguage; just don't complain when you're not understood.

Comment: @jlawler there's no reason to say the complementizer includes both 'for' and 'to,' unless you also want to say non-finite auxiliaries are complementizers in general. 'for' is the complementizer. it acts just like 'that' does in relevant respects. 'to' is a non-finite auxiliary. it acts exactly like non-finite 'have' and 'be' do, as shown in the cited paper

Answer (score 1):

That "for" is a complementizer.  If it were a preposition, it would take an object which could be pronominalized with "it" or "that", but *"John won't stay though I'd prefer for it".  On the other hand, when it is a complementizer, pronominalization of the entire nominalized construction may be possible: "John won't stay, though I'd prefer that."

Generally, the structure depends on the governing verb -- here "prefer".  Compare this with "wait".  "John won't stay, so don't wait for that" as compared with *"John won't stay, so don't wait that".  Here, the preposition interpretation is at least possible.

Comment: This is correct, it is a complementizer here. I'd like to add a couple arguments for this conclusion: (i) for+John doesn't appear to be a constituent (you can't move this string, as you could a PP), (ii) you get what looks like a Comp-trace effect by extracting _John_

Comment: The first observation is not convincing. The _that_ in _...I'd prefer that_ can be interpreted as standing in for the full clause. We actually have  _I'd prefer that John not stay_ --> _I'd prefer that_. This insight points to a flat structure, one in which both _John_ and _to stay_ are immediate dependents of _for_ in the sentence _I'd prefer for John to stay_. The flat structure is then supported by the results of most tests for constituents, which reveal that _John to stay_ does not qualify as a constituent.

Comment: @TimOsborne, Of course, I agree that "John to stay" is not a constituent -- who said it was?  "For" is not the complementizer here, it's for-to.  Your analysis seems no more than a pun -- "that" happens to be both a pronoun and a complementizer.  Beside "I'd prefer that" we also have "I'd prefer this/it" where the antecedent is also the sentential object of "prefer" in the previous sentence.

Comment: @Greg Lee, OK, I may have misread your answer. My point, though, is that we cannot be sure that _that_ replaces the entire expression _for John to stay_ because in such a case it could be replacing _that John stay_ instead. In any event, it's good that we perhaps agree that _John to stay_ is not a constituent. My guess, however, is that most of the other posters think _John to stay_ IS a constituent. I am currently producing my own answer in this regard. It'd be great if you then comment.

Comment: @TimOsborne Grammarians gave up on the replacement theory of pronominalization years ago in the face of the Bach-Peters paradox.

Answer (score -1):

The word *for* in the sentence *I prefer for John to stay* is neither clearly a preposition nor clearly a subordinator (aka complementizer), but rather it has a unique status. To help capture this unique status, one could coin a new term. One could call it an ***adpositional subordinator*** because it behaves as a preposition with respect to its nominal complement and like a subordinator with respect to the *to*-infinitive complement.

Let’s consider first some evidence suggesting that *for* in *I prefer for John to stay* is not a pure subordinator. Pure subordinators can take a finite clause as their complement, yet *for* cannot do this, e.g.

(1) *I’d prefer for John stay(s).

(2) *I’d prefer for that John stay(s).

If *for* were a subordinator like other subordinators, these sentences would be good. Since they are clearly bad, we can indeed conclude that *for* is not a pure subordinator.

Let’s consider next some evidence demonstrating that *for* in *I prefer for John to stay* is not a pure preposition. Most of the time, pure prepositions take a nominal complement alone; they do not take a *to*-infinitive complement as well, e.g.

(3) *On Tuesday to go home, we left early.

(4) *With Tom to leave early, I have spoken.

(5) *In two hours to go home, we are leaving.

The prepositions and their complements are fronted in these examples in order to avoid the confounding factor of the *to*-phrases being interpreted as rationale phrases. If the prepositions *on*, *with*, and *in* could take a *to*-infinitive complement like *for* can, these sentences would likely be acceptable.

The insights so far demonstrate that *for* should indeed be granted a special status in the grammar. It has special properties that cannot be captured by the simple designation *subordinator* or *preposition* alone. This situation is a problem for standard phrase structure approaches because such approaches are not well-equipped to address lexical idiosyncrasy. Thus, the approaches that BillJ, Tsutsu, Jlawler, Greg Lee, and matan-matika envision above cannot address the status of *for* in *I’d prefer for John to stay* in a convincing way, for they lack an appropriate category that captures its distribution. It is not the head of CP, IP, TP, etc. because these categories are all compatible with finite clauses, whereas *for* does not license such clauses, as demonstrated above with examples (1-2). The category PP is also not appropriate because the P of PP does not take a *to*-infinitive complement. Indeed, what is a phrase structure grammarian to do?

A dependency grammar (DG) approach is not faced with these difficulties because it conceives of sentence structure in terms of directed links, i.e. dependencies, between words. There is hence no need to force *for* into the one or the other preconceived category, for it is possible to produce a structural analysis without assigning *for* to any specific category at all. The DG analysis of the example sentence that I prefer is next:

[image]

This analysis is particularly strong insofar as both *John* and *to stay* are immediate dependents of *for*. The status of *for* as subordinator-like is accommodated in that the whole constituent *for John to stay* conveys the meaning of a proposition, i.e. of a complete clause, and the status of *for* as preposition-like is also accommodated insofar as it takes the nominal *John* as its immediate dependent similar to how a normal preposition takes a nominal as its immediate dependent.

Another important strength of the analysis is that the string *John to stay* is not a constituent, that is, it is not a complete subtree. This matches the fact that most tests for constituents fail to identify *John to stay* as a constituent, such as pronominalization, e.g. * *I prefer for that/it*. Note that the phrase structure analyses that BillJ, Tsutsu, matan-matika and others advocate for will likely construe *John to stay* as a constituent, contrary to what most tests for constituents actually reveal.

In sum, the question is good because it helps reveal a problem facing phrase structure syntax in general. The phrase structure template of syntactic categories (CP, TP, IP, PP, etc.) is hardly capable of addressing lexical idiosyncrasy. Dependency syntax presents a plausible alternative in this regard, one that has no problem with lexical idiosyncrasy.

Comment: But “John” is the agent of “stay”. How is this information captured in the tree? Apparently it isn’t at all.

Comment: @Atamiri, It is not captured in the tree because there is little if any syntactic evidence for the structure of the alternative analysis, that is, an analysis that subordinates _John_ to _stay_. Consider another similar sentence that can illustrate this point more clearly, e.g. _I want John to stay_. I think your reasoning from semantics wants to subordinate _John_ to _stay_. There is, though, very little syntactic evidence in favor of doing that. There is, though, plenty of evidence suggesting that the structure is flat. I can elaborate if you would like.

Comment: @Tim your argument that _for_ is not a complementizer rests on the assertion that CPs must be finite. there's no reason to accept that assertion. op's _for_-phrase is a non-finite CP with _for_ playing a role similar to _that_ in finite CPs. notice that constituency tests also don't give solid evidence for the complement of _that_ in finite CPs being a constituent, casting doubt on another part of your argument

Comment: @one-off-post I agree that constituency tests do not provide evidence for the complement of _that_ as a constituent, so my argument is not convincing in that area. I think your point is weak though insofar as there is no other subordinator (at least not that I am aware of) that cannot take a finite clause as its complement. The adpositional subordinator _for_ is unique in this area. Thus, my reasoning is still sound in that respect.

Comment: @TimOsborne I wasn’t referring to semantics. Virtually all syntactic theories explicitly assign grammatical functions/roles to dependents so I wanted to know how one can obtain this information from your tree. As for dependency/headship my reasoning comes from psycholinguistics (cognitive science) but this wasn’t the point here. Your tree is incomplete in this respect (just like X’ trees for example). Have you ever considered labelling the edges of your trees with grammatical functions or some sort of attributes?

Comment: @Atamiri, I have never been convinced about that aspect of dependency syntax. In a simple sentence such as _Jack saw Jill_, do we recognize that _Jack_ is the subject because there is a primitive syntactic function that is assigned to the relevant dependency or because _Jack_ immediately precedes the finite verb. I tend to think the latter is the better answer. In any case, coming up with a tractable inventory of syntactic functions is always fraught with difficulties. That this is so is evident in the variation across such inventories found in the literature.

Comment: @one-off-post, You have not responded to my last argument, i.e. that the adpositional subordinator _for_ is unique in its inability to take a finite clause as its complement. Should I construe your silence as a concession?

Comment: @tim no. there is no reason to think that complementizers should only combine with finite clauses. do a google search for "non-finite complementizer"

Comment: @one-off-the post That's not the point! The point is that _for_ seems to be the only subordinator that does not allow a finite clause as its complement. All the others that I am aware of (e.g. _that_, _before_, _after_, _because_, _if_,_when_,_where_, etc.), they all allow a finite clause as their complement. Does that make sense, and if it does, is it not a problem for the "normal complementizer" account of _for_?

Comment: @tim i don't understand why you think _for_-phrases being non-finite disqualifies them from being CPs. _for_ still has a clause as its complement, in particular a non-finite clause. _that_ also heads a clause, in particular a finite clause. that's what complementizer is, something whose complement is a clause. so why wouldn't we assume that a non-finite clause could have a complementizer? there's no comparative or theoretical reason as far as i know

Comment: @TimOsborne Have you considered other languages than English? In many languages if you want to say “Jack saw Jill” all 6 permutations are a well-formed sentence. How does one decipher the grammatical functions/roles in this case?

Comment: @one-off-post Attaching a category label to a word makes a prediction. In this case, the category label _subordinator_ incorrectly predicts the sentence _* I prefer for John leave(s)_ to be acceptable. What is needed is an approach that can acknowledge such syntactic idiosyncrasy. One needs to acknowledge subtypes, similar to how one acknowledges subtypes of, say, verbs (finite, infinitive, participle, etc.). With my designation _adpositional subordinator_, I have done just this.

Comment: @one-off-post Consider the matter also from the point of view of the CP category. In the phrase structure tree, the template is predetermined. Words are inserted into positions in the template. In this case, inserting _for_ into the C position incorrectly predicts that the finite complement should be possible, since it is possible for the other Cs. Now compare this situation with the dependency tree in my answer. The dependencies connecting _for_ to _John_ and _to_ are direct. No category label is needed, which means the problem concerning category status of _for_ does not arise.

Comment: @Atamiri, That is of course a matter of morphological case. Languages with freer word order tend to have the sentence participants marked morphologically. While there are indeed broad tendencies that can be acknoweldged, there is also much lexical idiosyncrasy that cannot be captured well using inventories of predetermined syntactic functions. My point is again supported by the variation across inventories of syntactic functions posited in the literature.

Comment: @TimOsborne, We think of things in very different ways. I don't care whether your diagrams capture various grammatical insights.  I care whether your theories are true or false.

Comment: @TimOsborne OK but there are languages with free word order and no morphological case so you still need some sort of labels or tags,

Comment: @Greg Lee, Hmmm.

Comment: @Atamiri, in those languages, such an example will be ambiguous.

Comment: @TimOsborne No, it won’t, it’s resolved by head marking.

Comment: @Atamiri, we need a concrete example to make this exchange accessible. I assume that some sort of animacy hierarchy will be crucial to the head-marking.